# Worst Case Region for a Convex Hull Heuristic

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, examples, computational-geometry, heuristics

I am currently implementing a heuristic algorithm for planar convex hulls hand would like to know, for which kind of strictly convex region it exhibits worst performance.
I know that there are many different [algorithms for calculating planar convex hulls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms), so there is no need to provide me with pointers to algorithms for *that* problem.
$$ $$
**The heuristic:**

the objective of the heuristic is a successive refinement of the convex hull starting with two points $p$ and $q$ of with minimal, resp. maximal x-coordinate, i.e. $x(p) < x(q)$.

Assuming that the points are in general position and, that the resulting hull shall be oriented counter clockwise, the heuristic is to

- start with the "digon" hull $\left\{(p,q),(q,p)\right\} := CH_0$
- construct $CH_{i+1}$ from $CH_i$ by inserting between the adjacent vertices $u$ and $w$ of each edge $\left(u,w\right)$ of $CH_i$ the vertex $v$ that is not yet in $CH_i$ and farthest to the right of $\left(u,w\right)$, thus effectively replacing $\left(u,w\right)$ with $\left(u,v\right),\left(v,w\right)$ (provided such $v$ exists)

It is obvious that the heuristic strives for creating a $CH_{i+1}$ of maximal area when epanding $CH_i$; the rationale for that heuristic thus is to be able to exlude a maximal subset of the points, that are not elements of the final convex hull.
Formulated differently, the heuristic strives for the fastest exhaustion of a polygonal convex area; the heuristic easily transfers to exhausting strictly convex regions.

$$ $$

> using the above heuristic for exhausting a (w.l.o.g unit area) disk yields a $CH_i$ with area $$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^i}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^i}\right)\frac{2^i}{\pi}$$.
> **Questions:**
>
> - is the circular disk the convex region with the slowest growing exhaustion-ratio and,  if it isn't,
> - what are examples of worse regions, resp.
> - which region is the worst?

Answer (score 2):

Unless I misunderstand your post,
you are describing the [QuickHull algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickhull)...?
The only difference I see is the order of growing each edge:
QuickHull's choice follows a recursion, you are processing
edges in counterclockwise order.
The growth of an edge to its farthest vertex is independent of
when that growth occurs, so the behavior is fundamentally the same.

---

[image: QuickHull]


<sup>(Image from [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickhull).)</sup>

---

The worst-case occurs when each step only incorporates one new point without
excluding any others. Points 
[non-uniformly distributed on a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14457421/387778)
achieve this, whereas uniformly distributed points on a circle do not.

---

[image]


<sup>(Image from [Guy Blelloch notes](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15499-s09/www/scribe/lec17/lec17.pdf).)</sup>

Comment: Yes, that is in the same spirit as the heuristic I described. I am however primarily interested in using the algorithm as a preprocessing step, before switching to asymptotically faster algorithms that require sorting; the interesting question is, how many iterations of the heuristic suffice to remove x percent of the area inside the convex hull, so that the remaining points will be sufficiently close to the convex, so that sorting them is justified.

Comment: @ManfredWeis: I think a worst-case point distribution could lead to arbitrarily small area inflation per step.

Comment: it is clear, that the area inflations will decrease rapidly and I am convinced, that the decrement is *slowest" for sufficiently dense points on a circle - simply because a circle maximizes the ratio of area/circumference (isoperimetric problem), but can that be proved or disproved?